# How to model enum types in phantom dsl?

Tags: scala, enums, cassandra-2.1, phantom-dsl

My case class contains enum parameter like as follows:

```
case class User(role: UserRole.UserRole, name: String)

object UserRole extends Enumeration {
  type UserRole = Value
  val ADMIN, USER = Value
}
```

How to model this case as in [this example](https://github.com/iamthiago/cassandra-phantom/blob/c23b6decbcf5eb72784d432fba98e9a4288056b2/src/main/scala/com/cassandra/phantom/modeling/model/GenericSongsModel.scala)?

Any code samples provided will be helpful.

Comment: I see, IntelliJ Idea was showing errors on the below line while the code compiles.
object role extends EnumColumn(this, UserRole) { override lazy val name = "role" }
So, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `EnumColumn`, which is created for this very reason. If you want to use the enum as a key, then you also need to create a primitive using the default helper methods.

You can use both flavours of defining an enum.

```
object Records extends Enumeration {
  type Records = Value
  val TypeOne, TypeTwo, TypeThree = Value
}

object NamedRecords extends Enumeration {
  type NamedRecords = Value
  val One = Value("one")
  val Two = Value("two")
}

object enum extends EnumColumn[Records.type](this, Records)
```

In your case this would be:

```
object role extends EnumColumn[UserRole.type](this, UserRole)
```

To use this as an index, you will need:

```
implicit val userRolePrimitive = Primitive(UserRole)
```

**Update** As of Phantom 2.0.0+

```
object role extends EnumColumn[UserRole](this)
```

You don't need to define any additional implicits, Enums  are now natively suported as indexes.

Comment: If the github example could be updated with all the possible scenarios of modelling data using phantom, it would be very helpful for us all. Great work, thanks Flavian.

Comment: Nice Answer! But got the working example from here - https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/d8afd1b34ebe514673e346041fb30223caadf469/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/outworkers/phantom/tables/BasicTable.scala#L68